# Php stripe SDK intermittent curl errors

Tags: php, curl, stripe-payments

Within the past week, I have been having intermittent networking errors when using Php SDK (uses curl client) to communicate with stripe credit card processing. It doesn't happen every time; however, the frequency is becoming more common.

I have traced the error to being related to curl

Network error [errno 28]: Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received

We are using stripe's SDK and that is the exception it is giving us. Stripe is not reporting any errors.

Do you have any ideas to figure this out?

```
object(Stripe\Error\ApiConnection)#312 (12) {
  ["message":protected]=>
  string(362) "Could not connect to Stripe (https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges).  Please check your internet connection and try again.  If this problem persists, you should check Stripe's service status at https://twitter.com/stripestatus, or let us know at support@stripe.com.

(Network error [errno 28]: Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received)"
```

Comment: if you can modify (and later roll-back) the curl calls, you could enable verbose mode in curl, and log that somewhere along with a dump of curlinfo. I dunno the stripe api, but maybe they have options whereby you could enable verbose curls with zero touch on the code. That would give you tons of information.

Comment: I might start with your host to troubleshoot this --- see if they have any firewalling, loss of dns or connectivity that could be causing this failure. Occasionally I've found Stripe's tool, https://github.com/stripe/stripe-reachability, helpful.